# HttpClient - Request was canceled - Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, blazor-webassembly

I am using a blazor web assembly project followed by a asp.net core web api and a shared project. When running my two projects and pulling up post man to perform a GET request `https://localhost:5011/api/WebReport/GatherAllReports` it hits the `ReporterRepository` from the blazor web assembly and when it hits the very first line `var response` it stays on that line then eventually after a really long time it says on postman...

**System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.**

> ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.
>
> ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
>
> ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
>
> --->
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been
> aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
>
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync(Boolean async)
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean async, Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

and much more other messages returned in postman.

**Is there a reason why this is occurring whenever I call the route endpoint for my web api controller?**

Web API Controller:

```
using BlazorReports.Services; // this contains the `ReporterRepository.cs` file

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class WebReportController : ControllerBase
{
    
    private readonly ReporterRepository_repo;

    public WebReportController (ReporterRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GatherAllReports")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var reportValues = await _repo.GetAll();
        return Ok(reportValues);
    }

}
```

`startup.cs` for web api:

public class Startup
{
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
Configuration = configuration;
}

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebAPI", Version = "v1" });
    });
    services.AddDbContext<ReportContext>(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

    services.AddScoped<IReporterRepository, ReporterRepository>();

    services.AddHttpClient<IReporterRepository, ReporterRepository>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5011/");
        });

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebAPI v1"));
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseCors(opt => opt
          .AllowAnyMethod()
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) 
          .AllowCredentials()); 

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

}

In my blazor web assembly project:

`IReporterRepository.cs:`

```
public interface IReporterRepository
{
    Task<List<Reports>> GetAll();
}
```

`ReporterRepository.cs:`

```
public class ReporterRepository: IReporterRepository
{
   
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions _options;

    public ReporterRepository(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
    }

    public async Task<List<Reports>> GetAll()
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("/ReportsPage/GatherAllReports");
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(content);
        }

        var results = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Reports>>(content, _options);
        return results;
    }

}
```

Comment: It sounds like a performance issue in your `IReportRepository.GetAll()` method, the contents of which you haven't included in your question.

Comment: Sorry, a bit confused by what you meant. I did include the contents of `IReportRepository.GetAll()`, please check `ReporterRepository` file the `GetAll()` method. @AndrewH

Comment: Is it just me or does the GET to `_httpClient.GetAsync("/ReportsPage/GatherAllReports")` create an infinite loop? The controller action for `/GatherAllReports` calls `ReporterRepository.GetAll()`

Comment: Yes, I was experiencing that infinite loop as well, no idea why that occurs. @AndrewH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going in infinite loop because your GetAll() method is calling itself. Your code should look like this:

```
public class ReporterAccessLayer
{
   
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions _options;

    public ReporterAccessLayer(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task<List<Reports>> GetAll()
    {
      try
      {
         return await httpClient.GetAsync<List<Reports>>("/ReportsPage/GatherAllReports");
      }
      catch
      {
         // do exception handling

      } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This file, I should implement this in my blazor web assembly project or would this need to be in my web api project? I realized that I am doing `services.AddHttpClient<IReporterRepository, ReporterRepository>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5011/");
            });` in my web api project when this should be inside of my blazor application. But I noticed that the blazor server project only contains a `startup.cs` file. Would I need to translate that and put this line of code in the `program.cs` of my blazor wa project?

Comment: I do not have a blazor server project, I am only wanting to use a blazor web assembly with a api project

Comment: No. only in the Web assembly project.  WA will have builder.Services.AddHttpClient("https://localhost:5011/",
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>(); and ReporterAccessLayer. WebAPI should have services.AddScoped<IReporterRepository, ReporterRepository>()

Comment: I see so this ReporterAccessLayer should be its own unique file i.e. `ReporterAccessLayer.cs` and be placed in the same folder that contains the `IReporterRepository.cs` and `ReporterRepository.cs`? On another note, inside of the overloaded constructor you have `_repository` but I do not see where that was initialized, is that from the `IReporterRepositer`?

Comment: For the `return await _httpClient.GetAsync<List<Reports>>()` it has a redline under `_httpClient.GetAsync` saying the non-generic method 'HttpClient.GetAsync(string?) cannot be used with type arguments.

Comment: If I already have a `GetAll()` in my `ReporterRepo` file, should I remove that since I am implementing it in the access layer file?

Comment: ReporterAccessLayer should be in wasm. The other two in WebAPI
 On constructor: there is no need. You should read up about how dependency injection works
Keep get all in reporter repo. That's where the data is actually being fetched. ReporterAccessLayer is just to call the controller and manage logistics around the http request.

Comment: I follow thank you! I implemented ` builder.Services.AddHttpClient("localhost:5011", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();` in the program.cs file for blazor wa but it said **blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100] Unhandled exception rendering component: An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.**

Comment: I then tried ` builder.Services.AddHttpClient("https://localhost:5011/", client =>
                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)); ` but I got the same error. I did ` return await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Reports[]>("api/ReportsPage/GatherAllReports");` If I go to the web api project and perform the get it works, it is just the blazor that returns that url but it is the correct url

Answer (score 1):

Your request is timing out because you have created an infinite loop.

`WebReportController.Get()` invokes `ReporterRepository.GetAll()` which in turn makes an HTTP request back to `WebReportController.Get()` and you're back where you started. For the pattern you appear to be using, where your controller actions call into a service class to perform business logic (which is a good pattern), you would call into your Data Access Layer where your report data is held. You are not actually retrieving any report data in the code you have provided.

For example:

```cs
public async Task<List<Reports>> GetAll()
{
    var reportA = await _reports.GetReportA();
    var reportB = await _reports.GetReportA();

    // do any further business logic or error handling here

    return new List<Reports> { reportA, reportB };
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That would make a lot of sense why this is happening. This data access layer file I would need to include this into my blazor web assembly project?

Comment: Presumably yes because your data should be stored somewhere that is accessible by the web assembly.